# JSON, XML or String concatenation

Tags: java, xml, json, blackberry

I am doing a new application where I want to choose which protocol to use in it. I tried the String concatenation and the XML before, but never tried the JSON Object. Well Which one of those three is better in terms of performance? I am aware that XML is way much better than string concatenation. So what to use? XML or JSON? Or maybe a new technology that I am not aware of?
Thanks in advance

**I am aware that XML is way much better than string concatenation**. Well in this I mean that in String concatenation, I am adding different values and splitters to a string and then looping to find the spliters on the device. like in the example:

```
String toSend = "test1////test2////test3////test4////test5";
```

Here the splitter is `"////"` and I am sending 5 values. Getting these 5 values will be much more slower than XML in case of thousands of values.

Comment: `I am aware that XML is way much better than string concatenation`: What are you doing exactly? Why compare String concatenation with XML/JSON?

Comment: Check my edited comments to see what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. :)

Well, actually I think a properly written code to split a string will be more fast than an XML/JSON parser, however XML/JSON parsers are reliable in terms of returning exactly the same data structure. For instance, how would you handle a case when your data itself includes splitters? If such case is impossible under your business logic, then you may just go with string joining/splitting. Otherwise it is better not to reinvent the wheel and just use XML/JSON (JSON is more lightweight).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of Objects you will be exchanging.
It also depends on the way you will request and use you objects.

If you want ot provide a REST service that exposes simples Objects will be accessible directly by as Javascript GUI. I would also go for JSON. But no hand-made String concatenation to build JSON. You can use a lib.

But I you plan to exchange more complex data, between various Java based "services". I would probably go for XML. Especially if you can first write the XSD that defines you XML objects. You will be able to generate Java class and let JAXB do the marshalling/unmarshalling boring stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I would choose JSON, it's very portable and lightweight (lighter than XML).